# "Missing application logs in drains Heroku Status #1372"

Tags: heroku

What does this mean? It's just a warning on my Heroku metrics dashboard and isn't seemingly affecting me in a negative way, but I'm worried it's secretly messing with something?

Comment: I'm getting it as well.

Comment: same here, am slightly concerned.

Comment: Same, I only started seeing it recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Heroku Status Twitter account has 3 tweets [starting yesterday](https://twitter.com/herokustatus/status/951480150289301505) regarding this incident. [The incident](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1372) began 2 days ago (January 10th as of this writing) as the bottom of the page says:

> Issue
>
> From 18:48 UTC (1:48 PM ET) we have been experiencing losses in log drains.
>
> Application log drains (add-ons and custom drains to external services) may have missing log lines.
>
> During this incident, heroku logs --tail can be used to monitor incoming logs and should not have missing log lines. This output can be redirected to a file for later use if desired: heroku logs --tail > /tmp/.log
>
> POSTED 2 DAYS AGO, JAN 10, 2018 20:22 UTC

It might affect you in a negative way if you rely on application logs for further analysis and record keeping.

Comment: Thank you!! So this isn't my fault then and I don't need to take any action to fix it?

Comment: @jomak73 I don't believe you need to take any action, unless you're relying on the logs for further analysis or record keeping.